# Const returning C++ method can't be bound with LuaBridge

Tags: c++, lua

I have a method with this signature:

```
const std::string GameObject::GetName()
```

And then I try to bind it with this line:

```
...
.addFunction("getName", &GameObject::GetName)
...
```

When I try to compile, this error comes up:

```
Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 
'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *' 
to 
'void *'
```

The error comes from here:

```
\include\luabridge\detail\Userdata.h, line: 354
```

Here is a snippet from the `Userdata.h`

```
  inline T* getObject ()
  {
    // If this fails to compile it means you forgot to provide
    // a Container specialization for your container!
    //
    return reinterpret_cast <T*> (&m_storage [0]);
  }

private:
  /**
    Used for placement construction.
  */
  UserdataValue ()
  {
    m_p = getObject(); //Line 354
  }
```

I can use const, and const & std::string as parameters, in those cases there are no errors.

Why does this error occur? How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in LuaBridge, so you should [report it](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge/issues).

As for fixing your project, just remove the `const`, it doesn't make sense anyway since you're returning a value.